# Cannot find symbol error, java seems to believe that the object/method does not exist

Tags: java, object, methods, symbols

```
class Person{
private String navn;    //a Person class, "navn" means "name" in norwegian

Person(String s){
    navn = s;
    }

public String hentNavn(){ //returns the name of the person
    return navn;
    }
}

class PersonBeholder<Person>{   //a container using an own implementation of
    private Lelem forste;      //a linked list
    private int ant = 0;   //number of persons currently in the list

    private class Lelem{
        Lelem neste;
        Person personen;

        Lelem(Person p){
            personen = p;

            }

         public Person hentPerson(){ //returns the Person object
            return personen; //being pointed to
            }
        }

    public void settInnPerson(Person denne){  //this is the method for
        Lelem lel = new Lelem(denne);     //appending a Person to the list
        lel.neste = forste;
        forste = lel;
        **System.out.println(forste.hentPerson().hentNavn());**
                    /*this is where it goes wrong*/
        ant++;

    }
}
class TestPersoner2{
    public static void main (String [ ] args){
    PersonBeholder<Person> pl = new PersonBeholder<Person>();
    Person Emil = new Person("Emil");
    Person Nils = new Person("Nils");
    pl.settInnPerson(Emil);
    pl.settInnPerson(Nils);
    }
}
```

## OUTPUT

```
TestPersoner2.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                       System.out.println(forste.hentPerson().hentNavn());
                                                             ^
 symbol:   method hentNavn()
 location: class Object
 1 error
```

Trying to get java to print the name of a person stored in a container with an own implementation of a linked list datastructure.

I have made an own list element class, used for making objects for each element that point to the next element in the list. The Lelem (list element) class contains a method for returning the Person object, and the Person class contains a method for returning the String "navn" which is the name of the person.

Java seems to think that this hentNavn() method does not exist, and i cannot see why. 
Can someone please tell me that it's just a stupid typo?

B

Comment: What is the declared return type of `Lelem#hentPerson()`? I bet it's `Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've made `PersonBeholder` a generic class, with a *type parameter* of `Person`. I suspect you meant to do something like *implementing* a generic interface, using `Person` as a type *argument*.

So within `PersonBeholder`, the name `Person` doesn't refer to your `Person` class - it refers to the type parameter, which the compiler doesn't know anything about.

Just change this:

```
class PersonBeholder<Person>{
```

to

```
class PersonBeholder {
```

and change your instantiation from this:

```
PersonBeholder<Person> pl = new PersonBeholder<Person>();
```

to:

```
PersonBeholder pl = new PersonBeholder();
```

and all will be fine.

If you *really* want your `PersonBeholder` class to be generic, give it a different type parameter name. I suspect you don't though.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it does not need to be generic, my paper says so:) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your generic parameter `Person` is hiding the class name `Person`. Change the generic parameter name. On a side note, these are the kinds of errors an IDE will help in quickly finding and fixing.

Comment: Where is `Person` the parameter declared? I can't see it

Comment: @JanDvorak - its on the PersonBeholder class (`PersonBeholder<Person>`).

Answer (score 1):

At line where error is reported `Person` means type parameter of generic class `PersonBeholder<Person>`, i.e. unknown type, not particular class `Person` defined above.  You can fix this either by renaming generic parameter or by renaming class `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) is incorrect.

Anyway, just remove the type parameter `Person` from `PersonBeholder`.

```
class PersonBeholder {   //a container using an own implementation of
    private Lelem forste;      //a linked list
    private int ant = 0;

    private class Lelem{
        Lelem neste;
        Person personen;

        Lelem(Person p){
            personen = p;

        }

        public Person hentPerson(){
            return personen;
        }
    }

    public void settInnPerson(Person denne){
        Lelem lel = new Lelem(denne);
        lel.neste = forste;
        forste = lel;
        System.out.println(forste.hentPerson().hentNavn());
        ant++;

    }
}
```